# Getting String from TextView inside from ListView adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

Here is a method I have:

```
public static void updateRowForReview(int itemRowPosition) {
    adapter.getWasReviewed(itemRowPosition);
    updateReviewAtPosition(itemRowPosition);
}


private static void updateReviewAtPosition(int position) {
    View view = listView.getChildAt(position - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    listView.getAdapter().getView(position, view, listView);

    TextView reviewTotalTV =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvReviewTotalForItem);
    String reviewTotal = reviewTotalTV.getText().toString();

    int reviewTotalInt = Integer.valueOf(reviewTotal) + 1;
    reviewTotalTV.setText(String.valueOf(reviewTotalInt));
}
```

No matter what I do, the `getText().toString()` will only return 1.  The `TextView` `tvReviewTotalForItem` is dynamic and has all sorts of values in each row of the list.  So not sure why it returns this.  Is my code wrong?

Also note, the position of the row is correct; it sets the text to the right list row, just the wrong value.

Comment: Have you tried logging `reviewTotalTV` to make sure it has things in it?

Comment: @Nile  Well, I have Logged the `String` and the `int` not that.. let me see and report back

Comment: @Nile  Well, I get what I thought:   'android.widget.TextView@42832080`

Comment: The problem is most likely due to the `listView.getAdapter().getView(position, view, listView);` call. As you get the row view directly from the `ListView` it would normally have all the values that you see so the `getView()` call wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Luksprog  That's the correct answer, probably should write down so I can mark correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to:

```
listView.getAdapter().getView(position, view, listView);
```

call. As you get the row view directly from the `ListView` with `getChildAt()`, it would normally have all the values that you see/want so the `getView()` call wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the following would fix your problem, but using a `Tag` would make it easier to handle. I would replace your code with this one to keep the total in a `Tag`attached to the `TextView`:

```
private static void updateReviewAtPosition(int position) {
    View view = listView.getChildAt(position - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    listView.getAdapter().getView(position, view, listView);

    TextView reviewTotalTV =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvReviewTotalForItem);
    int reviewTotal = 0;
    if(reviewTotalTV.getTag() != null){
        reviewTotal = (Integer) reviewTotalTV.getTag();
    }

    reviewTotal++;
    reviewTotalTV.setText(String.valueOf(reviewTotal));
    reviewTotalTV.setTag(reviewTotal);
}
```